# Flutter Web playing audio not working on iOS 14.6 on both Chrome and Safari

Tags: ios, flutter, audio

I tried to use both [audioplayers](https://pub.dev/packages/audioplayers) and [just_audio](https://pub.dev/packages/just_audio) to play audio from URL and it works on Windows browsers, Android browsers, and iOS 15+ browsers, but not working on iPhone of iOS 14.6.

The used code to play audios with audioplayers:

```
await audioPlayer.release();
audioPlayer.play(UrlSource(audioURL)); 
audioPlayer.onPlayerComplete.listen((event) {
       audioPlayer.release();
    });
```

Apparently I have read that iPhones used to prevent automatic audio playing and it works only with user interaction but doesn't work if I played the audios automatically without user interaction, I have tried this and this seems to be correct, but I want to play it without user interaction.

so is there a way to prevent this problem in Flutter?